# Server Side and Client Side Click on ASP.NET Linkbutton

Tags: jquery, asp.net, button, postback

I have a standard link button which has a OnClick handler. The handler runs a lengthy process. I would like to insert a client side handler that displays a "please wait" image while we're waiting for the operation to complete:

```
$("#<%= btnProcess.ClientID %>").click( function() {
  $("#loaderimage").show();
});
```

The idea is that the image will be cleared when the page posts back.

Is the right way to go about this? It seems not to work - does anyone have an example or best practice for this sort of thing?

Chris

Comment: what doesn't work? what is happening exactly?

Comment: I just hate those OPs who just post their question and dissapear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the below

```
function__doPostBack("clientIdOfSubmitButton", null)`
```

I think it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UpdatePanel` and `UpdateProgress` controls to do the task. [Here is a example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18238/The-UpdateProgress-Control-of-ASP-NET-AJAX-Extensi)

Other solution. First create a `WebService` (which will do the required task), call it from client side on button click and at the same time using javascript or jquery show image. And as soon as you got confirmation from the service that task has been completed hide this image and tell user that task has been completed.